# DOMDocument cannot change parentNode

Tags: php, php-5.5

I cannot change the `DOMDocument` `parentNode` from null. I have tried using both `appendChild` and `replaceChild`, but haven't had any luck.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   function xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument=null) {
      if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
          $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument;
          $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;
          xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument);
          echo $DOMDocument->saveXML();
      } else {
          if (is_array($mixed)) {
              $node = $DOMDocument->createElement('urlset', 'hello');
              $DOMDocument->parentNode->appendChild($node);
          }
      }
  }

  $data = array();

  for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
      $data['urlset'][] = array(
         'loc' => 'http://www.example.com/user',
         'lastmod' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
         'changefreq' => 'monthly',
         'priority' => 0.5
      );
  }

  header('Content-Type: application/xml');
  echo xml_encode($data);

?>
```

http://runnable.com/VWhQksAhdIJYEPLj/xml-encode-for-php

Comment: You don't return anything from esle block

Comment: I cant find the variable `parentNode` ...

Comment: move `echo $DOMDocument->saveXML();` after else block

Comment: Little bit confusing... can you display what is expected output?

Comment: @Michael Wilson I try at your link, I am right - it works after moving

Comment: @Makesh Anything :) now he receives blank

Comment: I am receiving `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<urlset>hello</urlset>`. That's why asked .. Check https://ideone.com/zUpg10

Comment: @Makesh i think you tried after i moved echo below else block

Comment: I wonder where the asker :)

Comment: Everything is working fine ... I found no issues. May be he might have `echoed` something before `header()` and confused with that. We can close the topic

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I forgot to change ```$DOMDocument->appendChild($node);``` to ```$DOMDocument->parentNode->appendChild($node);``` in the question. When I do change it, the script breaks and dosen't work.

Comment: Question has now been updated.

Comment: After putting the ```xml_encode``` function into a separate file and included it, I'm now recieved this error ```Fatal error: Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in /var/www/work_in_progress/michael/xml_encode.php on line 13```, this is exactly where the ```$DOMDocument->parentNode->appendChild($node);``` is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the document has no *parent* node you need to append the root node directly to the document, like this:

```
$DOMDocument->appendChild($node);
```

This works since `DOMDocument` extends `DOMNode`.

---

[Working example](http://3v4l.org/cAHqj):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function xml_encode($mixed, &$DOMDocument=null) {
    if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
        $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument;
        $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;
        xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument);
        return $DOMDocument->saveXML();
    } else {
        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            $node = $DOMDocument->createElement('urlset', 'hello');
            $DOMDocument->appendChild($node);
        }
    }   
}

$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $data['urlset'][] = array(
       'loc' => 'http://www.example.com/user',
       'lastmod' => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
       'changefreq' => 'monthly',
       'priority' => 0.5 
    );  
}

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo xml_encode($data);
```

---

Btw, if you just want to serialize an XML file, `DOM` is a bit overhead. I would use a template engine for this, meaning handle it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, when you create a new DOMDocument you don't have a root element yet, so you can just create it and add it to the document

```
//You could add this to the top of xml_encode
if($DOMDocument->parentNode === null) {
   $root = $DOMDocument->createElement('root');
   $root = $DOMDocument->appendChild($root);
}

//Your script working: 
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function xml_encode($mixed, $DOMDocument=null) {
    if (is_null($DOMDocument)) {
        $DOMDocument =new DOMDocument();
        $DOMDocument->formatOutput = true;

        //add here, but note that in the "else" it isn't sure if the DOMDocument has a root element 
        $root = $DOMDocument->createElement('root');
        $root = $DOMDocument->appendChild($root);
        xml_encode($mixed, $root);

        echo $DOMDocument->saveXML();
    } else {
        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            $node = $DOMDocument->createElement('urlset', 'hello');
            $DOMDocument->parentNode->appendChild($node);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you need the parentNode? you could do `$DOMDocument->appendChild();`